# Export ListView to Excel - Struggling with Painful performance

Tags: excel, vb.net, listview

I´m trying to optimize the output of an application I wrote sometime ago and although I achieved a lot in many fronts, I´m struggling to speed up the function that export the results of a listview to a .xlsx file.

I´m using Interop to do it, as shown below:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

And this is the function that exports the data in the listview:

```
Private Function ExportListViewTab5ToXLSxFile(ByRef FileNameWithoutExtension As String, ByRef OutputDir As String) As Boolean

        Try
            Dim objExcel As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
            Dim bkWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim shWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

            objExcel = New Excel.Application
            bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
            shWorkSheet = CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

            For i = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Columns.Count - 1
                shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = lvObjectsTab5.Columns(i).Text
            Next
            For i = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Items.Count - 1
                For j = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
                    shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = lvObjectsTab5.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
                Next
            Next

            shWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

            Try

                '/////////////////
                '// Save report //
                '/////////////////
                Try
                    shWorkSheet.SaveAs(OutputDir & "\" & FileNameWithoutExtension & ".xlsx")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("A exportação do relatório foi cancelada pelo usuário!", "Exportação cancelada!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Return False
                End Try

                '///////////////////////////////////
                '// Close EXCEL.EXE COM processes //
                '///////////////////////////////////

                bkWorkBook.Close()
                objExcel.Workbooks.Close()
                NAR(bkWorkBook)
                objExcel.Quit()
                NAR(objExcel)

                '//////////////////////////
                '// Open report in Excel //
                '//////////////////////////

                Process.Start(OutputDir & "\" & FileNameWithoutExtension & ".xlsx")
                Return True

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Falha ao exportar o arquivo '" & FileNameWithoutExtension & ".xlsx' para '" & OutputDir & "'", "Falha ao exportar relatório!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                "Detalhes do erro:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                ex.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Return False
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Falha ao exportar o arquivo '" & FileNameWithoutExtension & ".xlsx' para '" & OutputDir & "'", "Falha ao exportar relatório!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                            "Detalhes do erro:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                            ex.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

The listview contains 10 columns and it takes 4 minutes to export 2000 lines. It´s too much. I have Googled for hours and searched for several examples of performance issues, but all examples I found were similar to mine.

Does anybody could guide me in how I could improve the performance of my function using .NET code? In a typical scenario this listview is listing 15000 rows. I´m limiting to 2000 so it is less painful for the users.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: A common issue. Write all the text from the listview into a 2d array during your double loop. Then write the array to the worksheet all at once! NOT with a loop. Like `shWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns).Value = arrayFilledByDoubleLoop` This will write to A2 as the upper left corner of the output data..

Comment: You could also try the 'ClosedXml' NuGet package instead of interop.  In my app I create a spreadsheet of 85k rows, 18 columns in 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply all the values as a range all at once. Something like this might do it.

```
dim Values(lvObjectsTab5.Items.Count, lvObjectsTab5.Items(i).SubItems.Count) as object
dim Range as Excel.Range = shWorkSheet.Range("A1","J" & (lvObjectsTab5.Items.Count+ 1))

For i = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Columns.Count - 1
    Values(0, i ) = lvObjectsTab5.Columns(i).Text
Next

For i = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Items.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To lvObjectsTab5.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
            Values(i+1,j) = lvObjectsTab5.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        Next
Next
Range.value = Values
```

**EDIT:** insert the column headers on the Values matrix.

Comment: Jesus... The answer from @AugustoQ just reduced it from 12 minutes to 30 seconds... I think this thread will help a bunch of people with the same issue... Thank you!

Comment: The only side effect of this solution is that the header with the column names from the listview is no longer exported.

Comment: You can export the Headers as well, I forgot to put it on my code, but if you place the first row of the `Values(,)` matrix as the headers names, it will also have the headers names

Comment: Ok, so a little fix for the header: This ->> Values(0, i + 1) = lvObjectsTab5.Columns(i).Text should be this ->> Values(0, i) = lvObjectsTab5.Columns(i).Text otherwise the header is shifted 1 position to the right...

Comment: That is right!
Just edited the answer again.. Thanks :)